# Angular 2 Increasing text box in Input field

Tags: html, forms

I am a bit new to angular 2.  Using a form and have an `<input type="text">` field, but it seems like its limited to 1 line view.  Can I use something similar to textarea where I can increase the box by number of lines? Basically need to show a larger paragraph field for a form using input.

Comment: .... so use a `textarea`. This has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can use `<textarea>` element in angular.

```
<textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the height of the input field also through the *style*. Quite handy for reach text inputs like comments.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
   <textarea style="height: 150px" matInput></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```